# REACT QRCODE: Unable to import module [cirocosta/qcode-decoder]

Tags: reactjs, npm, qr-code

I am working on a React Web App which requires a QR Code Scanner,
I imported the package [QCodeDecoder](https://github.com/cirocosta/qcode-decoder) through npm, still when I did `import QCodeDecoder from 'qcode-decoder';`
it throws an error that the module not found. I checked in the npm_modules and it is there.

Answer (score 1):

I think `qcode-decoder` is not an npm package. I see it contains a `package.json` but the file they are using as `main` doesn't exist.

In the documentation they claim the package should be installed through bower so you might need to give it a try that way.